# imshow structure of smaller values in an array

Tags: python, matplotlib

Running something like

```
from pylab import *
M = zeros((5,5))
M[0,2] = 1
M[1,1] = 1
M[1,3] = 1000
M[2,2] = 1
imshow(M)
```

Results in:
[image]

Does anyone have any pointers for bringing out the crosshair structure in the image? Preferably without wholly killing the contrast between the large and smaller values?
This will need to work with negative numbers also - EDIT: in the sense of altering positive and negative points symmetrically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the crosshair you refer to...

```
>>> print M
[[    0.     0.     1.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     1.     0.  1000.     0.]
 [    0.     1.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
```

but regarding the plot, you can take the logarithm of your data to increase the color distance between the ones and the one thousand:

```
np.log(M-M.min()+1)
```

I would also suggest to do away with the interpolation, so you get:

```
imshow(np.log(M-M.min()+1), interpolation='None')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the index error (x index of last point should be 2). However, this doesn't work with negative data: the use of min will distort formerly negative points differently than positive ones.